# Ubuntu noob, slow choppy mouse movement

Tags: drivers, graphics, mouse, 64-bit, amd-graphics

I'm very new to Ubuntu and I am running into some problems. I downloaded 14.04 because my AMD drivers don't work on 16.10. I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual boot which works well. Everything seemed to be working correctly, but then I realized my DVI cable is connected to my mobo rather than my GFX card (r9 390). I plugged it into my 390 and the display came back on, but everything, including tabs opening/closing and mouse movement felt choppy. It felt like my refresh rate went to 30hz.. (my monitor is 144hz). I watched some tutorials and got it to say I was running in 144hz, but nothing changed and it still felt all slow and choppy. I went into video settings and changed the driver from the open source one to some other one that was listed, and now when my Ubuntu boots it is a black screen, DVI connected to either the card or the mobo.. /r/Ubuntu recommended I ask my question here, Looking for some help, like I said I'm a complete noob.

- i7 2600k
- sapphire nitro r9 390
- 16gb ddr3
- 500 gb SSD
- Zowie EC2-a on usb3.0

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tired different sensitivity?// Go to System > Preferences > Mouse and under Pointer Speed move the Sensitivity slider to your liking. Does that help?

Comment: I am now on 15.10, because i gave up and reinstalled. still same problem.